# Is "There will be no" valid in meaning of "There will not be"?

Tags: difference, negation, existentials

Yesterday I got a message that

> "There **will be no** introduction lecture"

Now, I'm not sure if it's a mistake or it's another grammatical way to say

> "There **will not be** a lecture".

If they are both valid, is there a difference between them? (such as register, etc.)

Comment: It is not a mistake. As you wrote, it has the meaning of "There will not be an introduction lecture"

Comment: @Geshode -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper then I will post it as one. I was just not sure, since it is so short.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a mistake.

As you wrote, it has the meaning of "There will not be an introduction lecture".